# Templated Helpers and SelectLists in the View Model don't mix: true?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

It seems like there's a disconnect in the advised best practices when it comes to including the data source of a select list in a view model. For example, many best practices blog posts will recommend something along these lines:

ViewModel:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel 
{
     [UIHint("SelectInvoiceType")]
     public int idInvoiceType { get; set; }

     /* snip */

     /* I'll use this in the view to generate a SelectList */
     public List<invoicetype> InvoiceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

But then when we get to the editor template, the Model object will be just the int, with no knowledge of the containing view model:

SelectInvoiceType.cshtml

```
@model int
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EditorFormItem.cshtml";
  List<SelectListItem> selList = /* nothing to say here, really */;
}
@section DataContent {
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model, selList, null)
}
```

So, unless I'm missing something, these two "best practices" -- templated view helpers and strongly-typed list data in the view model -- just *can't* be used together. You *have* to resort to stuffing your list data into the ViewBag. Sound about right?

Sorry to sound incredulous, but I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to resort to stuffing your list data into the ViewBag. Sound about right?

No. To me stuffing things in ViewBag/ViewData doesn't sound right. You should not use `int` as a model type to an editor template that is supposed to generate a dropdownlist. A dropdownlist consists of two properties: a scalar type to bind the selected value to and a collection to be used to generate the different options in this ddl.

So a more correct way would be the following:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [UIHint("SelectInvoiceType")]
    public InvoiceTypesViewModel Invoice { get; set; }

    ... some other properties specific to the view
}
```

where `InvoiceTypesViewModel` is a view model and doesn't contain any reference to domain models such as `invoicetype` in the list in your example:

```
public class InvoiceTypesViewModel
{
     public int SelectedInvoiceType { get; set; }
     public SelectList InvoiceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

then in your main view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Invoice)
```

and the editor template:

```
@model InvoiceViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedInvoiceType, Model.InvoiceTypes)
```

Comment: I like the idea in principle. I use the object.cshtml template almost exclusively, though, so there's no @Html.EditorFor() call for each property. But as long as I allow a TemplateDepth of >1, this oughta work.

Comment: Of course, now AutoMapper won't get the value into my model automatically. Sigh, more configuration.